# Is there any Spotify CLI client that works on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, spotify

I dislike the Spotify client for OS X. I'm looking for a CLI client. Any recommendation?

Comment: Have you tried [Despotify](http://despotify.se/), mentioned on the service's Wikipedia page? If so, what's wrong with it and the other clients based on it? If not, why not?

Comment: @DanielBeck I couldn't install it via homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Despotify](http://despotify.se/) can be installed on OSX, I personally installed it with homebrew with the command

```
brew install --HEAD Despotify
```

and subsequently ran `despotify`, you will be show how to use the program from there on in.

Comment: You should never need sudo for homebrew.